# Landscape orientation, half view. Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, view

My app works fine in portrait orientation but when i turn to landscape mode I see white square trough half view.

[image: http://screenshot.cz/22XZB/sss.png]

What's the problem?

Code of movie player

```
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: stream)
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    moviePlayer.view.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
}
```

Comment: The view controller displaying the movie player should report it's supported rotations via `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resize `moviePlayer` when its superview's bounds change.

One solution is to move this line:

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Into `viewWillLayoutSubviews` (if this is a view controller subclass) or `layoutSubviews` (if this is a view subclass).

Another is to use auto-layout instead of manual layout.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using `autolayout`, you must update the view's frame when orientation is done, to do so you can use the method

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

}
```

This methods is called every time when a orientation change is done and here you can update or set the frame of view to your needs.

> Another way is to use Autolayout which is much effective.